# How can refresh usercontrol in master page calling from different aspx page?

Tags: .net

There is a aspx page with Master page.
This master page has a usercontrol.

I use script manager in the aspx page. I was tyring to update label text in usercontrol (Master page) after click a button.

Comment: The simple thing ,if you want to do it from client side is, you can find the control using some script like Javascript/Jquery and take further action.

Comment: I was tring to do that but it doesn't work. Cause the webpage include update panel and user control is outside of the panel. Is there a way I can update usercontrol outside of update panel?

Comment: you can write a server side function that returns the `ClientId` using `FindControl` then add in the markup a JS function that returns `'<% YourFunction()%>'`. When it'll reach the client side it will return the ID as generated by asp.net, so you can refer you JS function whenever you need the ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the page you can do something like this:

```
WebUserControl1 wuc = (WebUserControl1) Master.FindControl("wucId1");
wuc.ucLabelText = "whatever";
```

where `WebUserControl1` is the name of your user control and `wucId1` is its ID in the master page.
Assumed you have in the user control an attribute named `ucLabelText` for the label's text

Comment: You need to write : (wuc .FindControl("ucLabelText") as Label).Text= "Changed Text";   But you could not find it directly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SivaGopal, that's why I added the assumption that the text of the label is an attribute of the user control (ie you add a property that sets and gets it's value to and from the Label's text (as DanielCasserly has done in the beginning of his answer))

Answer (score 0):

If you expose the text as a property in the usercontrol and then again from the master page to the aspx page and you can change it at run time. ie:

[user control]
public string LabelText
{
get { return lbText.Text;}
set { lbText.Text = value;}
}

[master page]
public string ucLabelText
{
get{ return ucUsercontrol.LabelText;}
set { ucUserControl.LabelText = value;}
}